# HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode emulator. Creating emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Tags: java, android, haxm

While starting my AVD manager, I even downloaded all the images, my Android emulator is not working and coming as black screen with below error:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd device
    Hax is enabled
    Hax ram_size 0x40000000
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
    emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
    emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    VCPU shutdown request
    EAX=00748cea EBX=3ffadb60 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
    ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00006d38
    EIP=3ffb6921 EFL=00010082 [--S----] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
    ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
```

My Device Settings:

```
Name: Nexus_One_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\XXXXX\.android\avd\Nexus_One_API_23.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: nexus_one

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus One

vm.heapSize: 100

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 23

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: yes

AvdId: Nexus_One_API_23

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 240

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus One API 23

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:36362a51e6c830c2ab515a312c9ecbff

hw.ramSize: 512

hw.trackBall: yes

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: no

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

HAXM has a bug with Intel's 7th generation processors.

The new HAXM 6.0.5 fixes this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174#c51